# XSLT Creating namespace dynamically

Tags: java, xml, xslt, namespaces, apache-camel

My source XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:DriverResponse xmlns:ns2="com/rsa/eosago/schema-1.1" xmlns:ns3="com/rsa/dkbm/schema-1.5">
  <IDCheckDriver>84714718</IDCheckDriver>
  <ErrorList>
    <ErrorInfo>
      <Code>2</Code>
      <Message>Принят в обработку</Message>
    </ErrorInfo>
  </ErrorList>
</ns2:DriverResponse>
```

Wanted output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsa:DriverStatusRequest xmlns:rsa="com/rsa/eosago/schema-1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <InsurerID>18800000</InsurerID>
  <IDCheckDriver>84714718</IDCheckDriver>
</rsa:DriverStatusRequest>
```

I expect this output using this XSL wich is called from Apache Camel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
<xsl:param name="RSA-InsurerID"/>
<xsl:param name="EOSAGO-schema-version"/>

<xsl:param name="schema" select="concat('com/rsa/eosago/schema-', $EOSAGO-schema-version)"/>
<xsl:variable name="schemaUrlDummy">
    <xsl:element name="ns2:dummy" namespace="{$schema}"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="NS" select="ext:node-set($schemaUrlDummy)/*/namespace::ns2"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="rsa:DriverStatusRequest" namespace="com/rsa/eosago/schema-{$EOSAGO-schema-version}">            

        <InsurerID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$RSA-InsurerID"/>
        </InsurerID>

        <xsl:element name="IDCheckDriver">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='ns2')]"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$NS"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns2:DriverResponse/IDCheckDriver"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Camel settings:

```
<setHeader headerName="RSA-InsurerID">
    <constant>18800000</constant>
</setHeader>

<setHeader headerName="EOSAGO-schema-version">
    <constant>1.2</constant>
</setHeader>

<to uri="xslt:com/rsa/eosago/xsl/DriverResponse2DriverStatusRequest.xsl"/>
```

The problem is that i get this error stacktrace

> Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://com/rsa/eosago/xsl/DriverResponse2DriverStatusRequest.xsl due to: Namespace prefix 'ns2' is undeclared.
>
> Failed to resolve endpoint: xslt://com/rsa/eosago/xsl/DriverResponse2DriverStatusRequest.xsl due to: Namespace prefix 'ns2' is undeclared.
>
> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Namespace prefix 'ns2' is undeclared.

Why compiler throws exception on namespace that was created dinamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very confusing. Why can't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="RSA-InsurerID"/>
<xsl:param name="EOSAGO-schema-version"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="rsa:DriverStatusRequest" namespace="com/rsa/eosago/schema-{$EOSAGO-schema-version}">            
        <InsurerID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$RSA-InsurerID"/>
        </InsurerID>
        <IDCheckDriver>
            <xsl:value-of select="IDCheckDriver"/>
        </IDCheckDriver>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Working demo: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifqv

Comment: Man, really thanks! Will have some vodka for you tonight!))))